# Sql Oracle sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with my query

```
select count(item_number),
       trunc(creation_date, 'MON') as creation_date
 from EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B 
where organization_id='300000021164768'
group by trunc(creation_date, 'MON')
```

THE OUTPUT ARE

```
1-3-2021: 200
1-4-2021: 150
1-5-2021: 300
```

I want the output like :

```
1-4-2021: the sum of the previous count will be 350
1-5-2021: will be 650
```

I want the result the current day and the previous month and the sum of the count of every month thank you

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a running total along with the aggregation:

```
select trunc(creation_date, 'MON') as creation_date,
       count(*) as this_month_cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by organization_id, order by trunc(creation_date, 'MON')) as running_cnt
from EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B 
where organization_id = '300000021164768'
group by trunc(creation_date, 'MON')
order by min(creation_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a running total

```
with monthly_data as (
  select count(item_number) cnt,
         trunc(creation_date, 'MON') as creation_date
   from EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B 
  where organization_id='300000021164768'
  group by trunc(creation_date, 'MON')
)
select creation_date,
       cnt,
       sum(cnt) over (order by creation_date) running_cnt
  from monthly_data
```